# Making a video with opencv, getting only 1 frame

Tags: python, opencv, video

I've been trying to add a video making module to my program using opencv, but try as I might I can't get the video to show more than 1 frame.
I got this example code while searching for answers
([Creating a video using OpenCV 2.4.0 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440400/creating-a-video-using-opencv-2-4-0-in-python))

```
import cv2
from cv import *

img1 = cv2.imread('i001.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('i002.png')
img3 = cv2.imread('i003.png')

height , width , layers =  img1.shape

video=cv2.VideoWriter('test.avi', CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X'),1,(width,height))

video.write(img1)
video.write(img2)
video.write(img3)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

This creates a video that runs for 3 seconds, but shows only the first image for all 3 seconds. Is there a codec error or am I missing something?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426637/writing-video-with-opencv-python-mac

Comment: try a different codec. it seems as a decoding/encoding matter. try `mjpg` or `i420` as the fourcc to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Thanks, the i420 codec seems to work, I've tried a bunch of them earlier that didn't.

Answer (score 0):

u can use :

```
 cv.WriteFrame(writer, image)
```

like this :

```
 import cv

 img1 = cv.LoadImage('i001.png')
 img2 = cv.LoadImage('i002.png')
 img3 = cv.LoadImage('i003.png')

 writer=cv.CreateVideoWriter(filename, fourcc, fps, frame_size, is_color)

 cv.WriteFrame(writer, img1)
 cv.WriteFrame(writer, img2)
 cv.WriteFrame(writer, img3)
```

look also :

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=createvideowriter#CreateVideoWriter